# C shell continue line inside parens

Tags: csh

I am trying to set a variable in csh like so

`set a = (341954, 630315, 594386, 985345, 389463, 206934, 459323, 869546 ... )`

with many numbers.

The problem is that there are really quite a lot of numbers and so it is inconvenient to have one extremely long line containing all these numbers.

I expected the line continuation character `\` to solve this problem, but instead using backslash in this way

```
set a = (485362, 459435, \
         943583 )
```

returns a syntax error `too many ('s`

Surprisingly google did not reveal any good answer for how to do this. I'm guessing that means, there just *is* no good way to do this, because csh is terrible.

My question is, is there actually a good way to do this? Using another shell such as bash, is not a solution given the constraints of my task.

Comment: make sure there are no white space chars after your "\" char. Also, look at your csh man page for limits. I recall being tripped up by have more than 1024 "words" in a command line. There is also a overall-maxiumum string-length-size for command lines, (like maybe 1024*1024?) Sounds like you may be reaching those limits. Good luck.

Comment: any luck with this ?

Answer (score 0):

CSH command parsing is simplistic, see http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html for a good long list.

I guess the simplest way to do what you want is to keep adding to the array by redefining the array every line:

```
set a = ()
set a = ($a 1 2 3 4 5)
set a = ($a 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Using a while loop I found that my version of tcsh is not so bad at this, the following program created a variable with 10000 items in 1.1s and 100000 words in 120s (on a fast laptop):

```
set a = ( )
set i = 0
while ($i < 5000)
  set a = ($a $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i $i)
  @ i = $i + 1
end
echo "Array is $#a long"
```

So you'll run out of CPU before the length of the array becomes the limiting factor.

Out of interest I also timed the equivalent on BASH -- it turns out to be  about 3-6 times quicker on tasks like this.